# Does (s, s-1) constitute a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

I came across this problem: is (S, S-1) a vector space? I don't think it is, here's my thought process:

*The zero vector will exist - 0*(s, s-1) = (0,0)

*Vector addition doesn't look right: (s, s-1)+(q,q-1) = (s+q, s+q-2), which doesn't have the same form as the original to my eye.

*Scalar multiplication: c*(s, s-1) = (cs, cs-c) which certainly doesn't look like the original.

So I would say that it fails by axioms 2 and 3. What do you think?

Comment: What is $s$ supposed to be?

Comment: Also, how are vector addition and scalar multiplication defined?

Comment: S would be some real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean: Is

$$\{(s,s-1): s \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

a vector space (for the usual operations).

The answer is negative: The zero vector $(0,0)$ is not in this set, so even the first axiom already fails...

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. The zero vector doesn't exist because there is no integer we can use for S that would make (s, s-1) = (0,0), is that right?

Comment: Alright then. When time permits, you can accept this answer when your question is solved so you let others know your question is solved. Welcome to MSE btw!

Comment: You bet. Sorry, still getting used to the process.